# plt.legend() only shows the first letter of the legend string

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

In the following code the legend should be the names specified in the list, but as you can see in the figure, only the first letter is shown.

```
bench = ['AA', 'BB']
offset = 0
for b in bench:
    L1 = [12+offset, 5+offset, 3+offset]
    L2 = [20+offset, 22+offset, 25+offset]
    offset += 5
    
    plt.plot(L1, L2)
    plt.legend(b)
    plt.savefig('test4.png')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `legend` not properly and you need to use the `label` argument.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bench = ['AA', 'BB']
offset = 0
for b in bench:
    L1 = [12+offset, 5+offset, 3+offset]
    L2 = [20+offset, 22+offset, 25+offset]
    offset += 5
    
    plt.plot(L1, L2, label=b)
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('test4.png')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: OK. I see two separate figures. How did you see them in one figure?

Comment: You mean, you see the orange line in one figure and the blue line in another one? That's exactly the code the I have used to plot the image above, no lines missing.

Comment: Yes I see two figures as I posted.

Comment: Are you using Spyder IDE and plotting in the Plots tab?

Comment: OK that was Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

`plt.legend()` takes an iterable of labels, so if you only need the label with everything else unchanged, you can replace

```py
plt.legend(b)
```

with

```py
plt.legend([b])
```